# Oracle: instr+substr instead of regexp_substr

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, instr

I got this query from another post I made which uses `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` to pull out specific information from a string in oracle. It works good but only for small sets of data. When it comes to tables that have 300,000+ records, it is very slow and I was doing some reading that instr + substr might be faster. The example query is:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(^|\|)\s*24=\s*(.*?)\s*(\||$)',  1, 1, NULL, 2)  AS "24",
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(^|\|)\s*35=\s*(.*?)\s*(\||$)',  1, 1, NULL, 2)  AS "35",
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(^|\|)\s*47A=\s*(.*?)\s*(\||$)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) AS "47A",
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(^|\|)\s*98A=\s*(.*?)\s*(\||$)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) AS "98A"
FROM   table_name
```

*Table example*:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value ) AS
SELECT '35= 88234.00 | 47A= Shawn | 98A= This is a comment |' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '24= 123.00 | 98A= This is a comment | 47A= Derick |' FROM DUAL
```

Output of query would be:

| 24 | 35 | 47A | 98A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 88234.00 | Shawn | This is a comment |
| 123.00 |  | Derick | This is a comment |

Can someone give me an example of how this same query would look if I was doing instr+substr instead?

Thank you.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired result, and explain your logic.

Comment: Edited my original post with more details.

Comment: Yes, the regexp_substr query does produce the output.

Comment: Your regexp query allows an unknown number of spaces before the hardcoded `24=` and similar. Is that important? If it is, it will be a bit hard to solve the same problem with standard INSTR and SUBSTR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN start_24 > 0
       THEN TRIM(
              SUBSTR(
                value,
                start_24 + 5,
                INSTR(value, '|', start_24 + 5) - (start_24+5)
              )
           )
       END AS "24",
       CASE 
       WHEN start_35 > 0
       THEN TRIM(
              SUBSTR(
                value,
                start_35 + 5,
                INSTR(value, '|', start_35 + 5) - (start_35+5)
              )
           )
       END AS "35",
       CASE 
       WHEN start_47a > 0
       THEN TRIM(
              SUBSTR(
                value,
                start_47a + 6,
                INSTR(value, '|', start_47a + 6) - (start_47a+6)
              )
           )
       END AS "47A",
       CASE 
       WHEN start_98a > 0
       THEN TRIM(
              SUBSTR(
                value,
                start_98a + 6,
                INSTR(value, '|', start_98a + 6) - (start_98a+6)
              )
           )
       END AS "98A"
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR(value, '| 24=') AS start_24,
         INSTR(value, '| 35=') AS start_35,
         INSTR(value, '| 47A=') AS start_47a,
         INSTR(value, '| 98A=') AS start_98a
  FROM   (
    SELECT '| ' || value AS value FROM table_name
  )
);
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | 24 | 35 | 47A | 98A |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> |  | 88234.00 | Shawn | This is a comment |
> | 123.00 |  | Derick | This is a comment |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b15f35403fd7dcf43d6f66e9c11dd76)*

Comment: This is perfect thank you. The query I was using was taking over an hour to run and with this new example, I modified my query and it now takes 2 minutes and 28 seconds to run.

Answer (score 0):

Given the data in your example it seems you could also use a procedural approach for your data extraction, but I'm sceptical if this could be faster.

The following function `get24` for example extracts the columns "24" just using `INSTR` and `SUBSTR`.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get24(value IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    i PLS_INTEGER;
    s VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  i := INSTR(value, '24= ');
  IF (i <> 1) THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  s := SUBSTR(value, i + 4);
  i := INSTR(s, ' | ');
  IF (i = 0) THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN SUBSTR(s, 1, i - 1);
END;
/

SELECT get24(value) "24" FROM table_name;
```

You could then also try using a pipelined function and do all the data extraction within the pipelined function.

Comment: If the OP's data includes `124= abc | 24= def |` then this would get `abc` and not `def`. You would need to include a leading delimiter to prevent this.

Comment: Correct; this should also need to be considered. I mostly wanted to offer a procedural option but I really like your pure sql solution.

Comment: You could make it generic [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=272a3c91c91f4d692f0188ae5c946e17).

Comment: Just tested it and with a large data set, the functional approach is actually slower. Without having it tested, I would rather go for a pipelined function if using a procedural approach. In real live I would probably decide based on how static the extraction of the columns is.